# Alterar o idioma do resultado de um web-scraping com rvest a partir do site do IMDB

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Quero coletar informações sobre o Top 250 do IMDB usando o pacote `rvest`. Ao visitar o [link da página](https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/), os nomes dos filmes aparecem em seu idioma original, ao menos no meu navegador (Firefox 85.0.1, macOS 11.2, ambos em inglês):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, ao fazer o web-scraping, meu R (4.0.3, locale `en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8/C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8`) baixa os nomes dos filmes em português:

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

imdb_url <- "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/"

imdb <- 
  read_html(imdb_url, options = ) %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  .[[1]] %>% 
  select("Rank & Title", "IMDb Rating")

head(imdb, 5)
#>                                               Rank & Title IMDb Rating
#> 1          1.\n      Um Sonho de Liberdade\n        (1994)         9.2
#> 2              2.\n      O Poderoso Chefão\n        (1972)         9.1
#> 3           3.\n      O Poderoso Chefão II\n        (1974)         9.0
#> 4 4.\n      Batman: O Cavaleiro das Trevas\n        (2008)         9.0
#> 5       5.\n      12 Homens e uma Sentença\n        (1957)         8.9
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Eu gostaria que os nomes dos filmes estivessem em inglês, como na página que visualizo em meu browser. O que posso fazer para resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar `httr::add_headers` para especificar a linguagem desejada:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)

imdb <-
  paste0(imdb_url, "/textlist") %>%
  html_session(add_headers("Accept-Language" = "en")) %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  select("Rank & Title", "IMDb Rating")

> head(imdb)
                                        Rank & Title IMDb Rating
1 1.\n      The Shawshank Redemption\n        (1994)         9.2
2            2.\n      The Godfather\n        (1972)         9.1
3   3.\n      The Godfather: Part II\n        (1974)         9.0
4          4.\n      The Dark Knight\n        (2008)         9.0
5             5.\n      12 Angry Men\n        (1957)         8.9
6         6.\n      Schindler's List\n        (1993)         8.9
```

Comment: Excelente. Obrigado!